# An ordinary Differential Equation which has no solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Can we think of an Ordinary Differential Equation which has no solution?

How can we think of this ODE?

Like what $f$ should I use such that $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$ with $y(x_{0}) = f(x_{0},y_{0})$.

From existence theorem I think I have to use a $f$ which is not Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574962/differential-equation-with-no-solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lipschitz condition is needed for uniqueness, not existence.  As long as $f(x,y)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $(x_0, y_0)$ there is a solution.

For a simple example of non-existence, consider the d.e. 
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \cases{1 & if $xy < 0$\cr
               -1 & if $xy \ge 0$\cr} $$
with initial condition $y(0)=0$.

Comment: Nice, but I was thinking  why a product of $x$ and $y$ was taken while defining $f$, cannot I define $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ if $x <0$ and $-1$ if $x \geq 0$?

Comment: You could do that too, but $y = -|x|$ would be a solution everywhere except at $x=0$ itself.  In my example, the nonexistence is a bit more extreme.  There is no solution on an interval $(0,\epsilon)$ or $(-\epsilon, 0)$ with $\epsilon > 0$ that has one-sided limit $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Illustrative, but I was thinking why your argument will work if you have the product $xy$ that is $xy \geq 0$ and $xy \leq 0$, like I could visualize why the above mentioned solution by me will not work when i think of $y =|x|$ graph but how could I visualize in your case when $xy\geq 0 $and $xy \leq 0$ is involved?

Comment: Also, I think why $y = -|x|$ will not be a solution to the ODE you said, as I observe $y=-|x|$ satisfies the conditions of the function $y$?

Answer (score 4):

Derivatives have the [Darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), that is, if $g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in the interval $I$ and $g'$ takes two distinct values, then it takes all the values in between. So in order to have an ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ with no solutions, we can take $f(x,y)=g(x)$ where $g$  is any function with jump discontinuities like the [Dirichlet Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html).